# Is it possible to define valid C# interface that cannot be implemented?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm thinking about this (meta) question for couple of days already:
**Is it possible to define valid C# interface, that cannot be implemented in any way?**

Possible variations of this question: Is it possible to define such interface in **C# 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0**? Is it possible to define such interface that would not even compile when implemented, or that would compile but throw runtime exception?

**Edit**: I know such interface will be useless just by definition, but is a nice answer for lectures or testing applicants for a programming job how good they know C#.

Comment: I'm very curious about the purpose of such an interface

Comment: I would consider this to be a pretty poor question to test someone's knowledge of C# if the position in question is for a developer who will be using the language as a tool, since it is not a practical problem that they'll face on the job. However it's actually not too bad a question if the position is a spot on the compiler testing team.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. That doesn't mean it should be deleted, but before you vote to re-open, think to yourself: *Do we really need more answers to this question?*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it possible to define valid C# interface that cannot be implemented?

This trivia question is not a good fit for StackOverflow, but what the heck, it is easily answered. (Wrongly, as it turns out! Read on!)

```
class C
{
    private C() {}
}
interface IFoo<T> where T : C, new()
{
}
```

`IFoo<T>` cannot be implemented for any `T` because there is no type argument that can be substituted for `T`. `C` doesn't work because `C` does not have a public parameterless constructor, and there can be no derived class of `C` because the default constructor is private. (Well, there could be an accessible derived class of `C` inside `C`, but there isn't in this case.)

---

UPDATE: Commenter "mike z" correctly points out that

```
class X<T> : IFoo<T> where T : C, new() {}
```

implements the interface, though of course now there is no way to instantiate `X<T>`!

Even better, user "GranBurguesa" points out that a derived class of C is permitted to be declared, just so long as it never calls the private constructor; this is only possible if it crashes and dies on instantiation. (Well, to be picky, it would also be permitted for the recursive calls to be optimized down to an infinite loop instead of a crash.)

Both devious workarounds pose a philosophical question: if an interface is implemented by a class no one can instantiate, is it really implemented? Of course GranBurguesa demonstrates that `IFoo<D>` can be implemented and constructed, so my answer is actually wrong.

---

There are also cases, such as the one hinted at in SLaks' deleted answer, in which an abuse of the generic mechanism leads to an "infinitary" type. Such types are not legal in the CLR; the C# design team has considered adding similar language to the C# compiler spec but hasn't gotten around to it yet. Use of these types can crash the compiler or the runtime.

For an example of an infinitary type that crashes the compiler, see my article:

[To Infinity But Not Beyond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx)

---

Here's one.  Cut n paste this code into Visual Studio and you'll see that this interface cannot be implemented:

`interface ΙAmAPerfectlyOrdinaryInterface { }`

`class C : IAmAPerfectlyOrdinaryInterface { }`

Comment: But why does this even compile? Isn't it statically clear that C's constructor is not accessible in any way and therefore there isn't any T that can meet the constraints? Shouldn't the compiler catch this?

Comment: This is a nice example, thanks.

Comment: I tried a whole bunch of variants using generic constraints, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: @InBetween: The answers to your three questions are: (1) because it is a legal program, (2) yes, and (3) the compiler is not required to catch every dumb thing that a developer does; the compiler is only required to catch the ones that the specification says it is required to catch. Error detection is *expensive* and *difficult* and so like any feature, error detection algorithms must be prioritized against other features in terms of their costs and benefits. The benefit of such an error detector is very small because this is highly contrived code, and the consequence of the error is obvious.

Comment: If I defined `class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : C, new() { }` would that not implement the interface? I realize, as you stated, there is no actual type `T` that could be used. Is there some general term used to distinguish a "substantive" implementation (which does not exist here) from a "non-substantive" one (like `Foo<T>`)?

Comment: @mikez: You are absolutely right; I did not consider that. Nice one!

Comment: @EricLippert: Is an open-form generic really a "class"?  Certainly an open-form generic like `IEnumerable<>` is a `Type`, since the type system needs to have something to which the generic parameters can be attached, but I don't think there's any way to, e.g. cause a static class constructor to run for an unbound generic, is there?

Comment: @EricLippert: Are there any cases where it should *legitimately* be possible to load a class which does not contain any calls to an accessible base constructor?  I wonder if the CLR should be patched to prevent the loading of such classes, since at present nothing prevents a derived class from producing instances and exposing them to outside code (see my answer for an example of how that may be accomplished).

Answer (score 9):

As long as we're talking trivia, I think this is a valid implementation of Eric Lippert's attempt:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        D test = new D();
    }
}

class C
{
    private C() { }
}

interface IFoo<T> where T : C, new() { }

class D : C
{
    public D()
        : this(5) { }

    public D(int x)
        : this() { }
}

class Dfoo : IFoo<D> { }
```

It compiles fine but crashes with a `StackOverflowException` when you instantiate `D`.

Comment: I was on the C# compiler team for the better part of a decade and I still learn new stuff about this language all the time. I did not realize that the compiler would allow you to override a class if the base class ctor was never called, but of course this makes perfect sense. Thanks for this great example!

Comment: I'll do you one better: the lack of CLR validation of parent calls makes it possible to construct derived-type instances and expose them to parent code.  See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to factor out an old interface you could mark the interface with the [`ObsoleteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) attribute.

**Edit:** as *@Magnus* noted in the comments, if you set the [`Error` attribute to `true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.iserror.aspx) it's usage will cause an error.

Comment: That does not render the interface unusable, though.

Comment: @Renan if the `error` parameter is set in the ctor it is pretty much unusable.

Comment: @Magnus didn't know about that property ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.iserror.aspx

Comment: In that case I would like to remove my downvote, however now I can't unless the post is edited :/

Answer (score 5):

If a type is accessible and unsealed, it will be possible for outside code to create instances of that type and there isn't really anything the base type can do about it.  No "full trust" or Reflection required.

```
public class CantDeriveMe
{
    private CantDeriveMe()
    {
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "My type is " + this.GetType().ToString();
    }
}

public class OhYeah : CantDeriveMe
{
    static OhYeah CapturedInstance;

    ~OhYeah()
    {
        CapturedInstance = this;
    }

    OhYeah() : this(1/String.Empty.Length)
    {
    }
    OhYeah(int blah) : this()
    {
    }
    public static OhYeah Create()
    {
        try
        {
            new OhYeah(4);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
        return CapturedInstance;
    }
    public static void test()
    {
        OhYeah it;
        it = OhYeah.Create();
        Console.WriteLine("Result was ({0})", it);
    }
}
```

Note that if code is written only in C#, a base-class destructor might squawk if it notices that the object isn't of a legitimate type, but code written in languages other than C# would allow the override of `Finalize` to exit without chaining to its parent.

I think it's possible to specify an open generic interface with a combination of `struct` and class constraints which no combination of types could possibly fulfill, e.g.

```
public interface evil<T, U>
    where T : struct,U
    where U : class
```

I'm not sure whether such an open-generic type would really qualify as an "interface", though, or whether only closed generic types can really qualify as interfaces (or classes, or structs).

Comment: Holy goodness this is devious. Nice work.  I wonder if there is an attack you could mount based on this?

Comment: I dont understand you. What's stopping me from doing `class MyClass : evil<int, IConvertible>` ?

Comment: @nawfal: Hmm... Only thing stopping *me* was that I forgot the distinction between interfaces and interface-type storage locations, which is ironic since I've written often about it.

Comment: @EricLippert: I think the class that wants to limit inheritance could prevent such a trick by declaring a new protected virtual method named `Finalize`.  It's too bad there's no way to declare a new sealed virtual method, since having `Finalize` sealed would prevent any class that tries to override it from even loading.  That would require changing the classes that are supposed to forbid inheritance, though.  Do you think any legitimate programs would break if the .NET class loader were changed to forbid classes which have at least one constructor but no chained calls to a parent constructor?

Comment: @EricLippert: As for mounting an attack, it is certainly possible to construct instances of derived types that the base class isn't expecting.  Personally, I think `Finalize` should be a member of something like `System.FinalizableObject` rather than `System.Object`, since in most cases where a class `Foo` would inherit finalizer-less `Bar` but hold an unmanaged resource, the proper approach is to encapsulate the resource into its own class object (which could inherit `FinalizableObject`) and have `Foo` hold a reference to that.  Too late for that now, though.

Comment: @supercat: I can't imagine that your proposal would break any real code.

Comment: @supercat hmm, the problem is `class` constraint which is slightly misleading (which takes both classes and interfaces). Similarly `struct` constraint which takes both structs and enums. `ref` or `val` would have been better..

Comment: @nawfal: Boxed value-type objects behave like class types rather than value types; a Framework type which demonstrates this is `List<T>.Enumerator`.  I wish `System.ValueType` had included virtual boxing and unboxing methods, since the semantics associated with implicit boxing and unboxing are not appropriate for all types.